# Ruby: reading files in turn

Tags: ruby

I have 2 files which should be run in order. I create run.rb file:

```
files =[
  './file-name-1.rb',
  './file-name-2.rb',
]

files.each do |file|
  require file
end
```

And run it. Are there more correct methods of solving this problem?

Comment: Why the array? Why not just require first and then require the other? Better yet, require first file from the second, so that even if you require the second file first, the order is maintained correct.

Comment: First file create other file with data, which process second file. If data-file not create, second file show error. Files will be greater than 2. Maybe I'm wrong in my logic.

Comment: It doesn't matter. All of the above suggestions still stand. I'd require first file from the second, since it's its implicit dependency. Better make it explicit.

Comment: @alexin are you saying that you're generating ruby files dynamically, which then need to be required after they're generated?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the advice!

Comment: @JonCairns,  generating csv files.

Comment: I find the idea of requiring a file doing something else than declaring classes,methods etc to be unappealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is `file-name-2.rb` that depends on `file-name-1.rb`, then it should be the one to `require "file-name-1.rb"`. It should not be `run.rb`'s job to know what another file's dependencies are. The correct way to solve this, then, is:

#### file-name-2.rb

```
require "file-name-1.rb"
# ...
```

#### run.rb

```
require "file-name-2.rb
# ....
```

And, as Frederick suggests in the comments above, it's unorthodox for a file to do work other than declaring constants (classes, modules) and/or methods at the time it's required. Instead, it should define methods to do that work, and then other files that `require` it can invoke those methods. This way you always know exactly when the work will be done, even if your application has a complex dependency structure.